# Percentage of an element relative to the whole layout in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

how can i get the percentage of an element depending on the whole layout? I tried to change the rulers to percent but the values are not accurate (859%, 1100%...).

Answer (score 0):

1.Change to procent, 
    2.view info panel F8 
    3. select to layer with the object. 
    4. cmd+t or ctrl+t now you se the element with and height with 1 decimal.